# Why isn't python binance recognizing symbols with GBP?

Tags: python, cryptocurrency, binance

I'm using the pything-binance API and trying to trade ethereum-gbp, for which I think ETHGBP is the symbol.

I have some code that's connecting to the live candle stream using the symbol and working as expected, however when I try to use it with the python-binance api to get historic data, I get an exception that it's an invalid symbol:

```
symbol = "ETHGBP"
klines = client.get_historical_klines(symbol, Client.KLINE_INTERVAL_1MINUTE, "14 minutes ago UTC")
```

I've tried with ETHUSD which works as expected.  What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you create the `client` are you specifying the correct `tld` parameter for the exchange you use?

If you want to interact with the main exchange, then no `tld` parameter is required and it defaults to `com`

Comment: I'm interacting with the main exchange.  I'm not sure why ETHGBP wouldn't be listed there